# CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript causing many memory leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cfnetwork

`CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript` is Apple's native API, defined in CFNetwork framework.Whenever I call this API many memory leaks are left by this API and they keep on piling with each call to this API.I found it using **"Instruments"** and **"View Memory Graph Heirarchy"** option too. At the end it crashes due to memory issues.

Below is the sample code that I am running.

```
CFErrorRef err = NULL;
NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com";
CFStringRef tempPacdata = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)pacFileData);
CFURLRef tempURLref = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)strURL, nil);
CFArrayRef proxies = CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript(tempPacdata, tempURLref, &err);

strURL = nil;
if (proxies != NULL)
{
CFRelease(proxies);
proxies = NULL;
}

if (tempPacdata != NULL)
{
CFRelease(tempPacdata);
tempPacdata = NULL;
}
if (tempURLref != NULL)
{
CFRelease(tempURLref);
tempURLref = NULL;
}
```

Here is the screenshot from Memory Graph

[image]

Has anyone else facing this issue and got any remedy for this?Any random thoughts are welcome too.

Comment: I made a little test app and I'm experiencing leakage too. But in my test, I'm getting a NULL proxies array back, as well as an error code 308 (can't find a definition for that.) I'm wondering if maybe the function leaks when it fails (which would of course still be a bug). Out of curiosity, are you getting a proxies array back in your code?

Comment: @TyR because you dont included pac file in your project thats why it fails.I am able to get proxy but with lot of leaks.Seems this API internally have leaks associated with it.

Comment: I was using a dummy PAC script in my test, but I forgot to wrap it inside findProxyForURL() {}, which was the problem. Now I am getting a proxies array back, but still lots of leakage. It's hard to imagine that Apple would have a leak like this in such mature production code, but I'm having a hard time finding another explanation.

Comment: As an experiment, I tried intentionally over-releasing the proxies array by sending it two CFRelease in a row. It A) did not alter the behavior of the leak, and B) did not cause a crash as it should have! Weird stuff- it really does look like the APIs are over-retaining some things. I think it's worth filing a bug report.

Comment: @TyR May be you are testing it on a simulator or high end device.It does crash on 5c and iphone 6 as well.Is there any way we can manually clear the memory leaks?Just a random thought!

Comment: Reported bug to Apple.Lets see what they say.

Comment: I was building for Mac not iOS- leaks like crazy on Mac too.

Comment: So, did they said anything?

Comment: They said they will fix it but no timeline, its not fixed on iOS 12

Comment: @DesertRose Still seeing this on macOS 12.4 using the CF c api. Is there any update on the issue you have filed? Thanks.

Comment: They asked me to test on iOS 16 without saying anything about fix. I didn't test as I have written my own framework for this whole implementation.